# Tkinter сохранения документа с паролем

Tags: python, tkinter

Пишу текстовый редактор на Python3.8 Tkinter и хочу реализовать чтобы можно было при сохранении файла присваивать ему пароль и потом когда его открывать то просило пароль?  Как это можно сделать

Comment: не важно, в каком расширении сохранять файл?

Comment: Нет не важно!!!

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое, но не самое надежное решение:

```
import json
from tkinter import simpledialog as sd, messagebox as mb

# Функция, сохраняющая заданный текст с заданным паролем по заданному пути
def save_with_password(text, password, path):
    obj = {'text': text, 'password': password}
    to_save = open(path, 'w')
    to_save.write(json.dumps(obj))
    to_save.close()

# Функция, открывающая запароленный файл
def open_passworded_file(path):
    f = open(path, 'r')
    data = json.loads(f.read())
    f.close()
    password = sd.askstring(title="Ввод данных", prompt="Введите пароль")
    if password == data['password']:
        return data['text']
    else:
        mb.showerror('Ошибка','Неверный пароль')
```

Чтобы сделать надежнее - можно кодировать то, что записываем в файл, а при чтении декодировать

Пример с самым простым кодированием/декодированием:

```
import json
from tkinter import simpledialog as sd, messagebox as mb
import base64

# Функция, сохраняющая заданный текст с заданным паролем по заданному пути
def save_with_password(text, password, path):
    obj = {'text': text, 'password': password}
    to_save = open(path, 'w')
    data = json.dumps(obj)
    encoded_data = base64.b64encode(data.encode()).decode()
    to_save.write(encoded_data) # сохранится казалось бы всякая абра кадабра
    to_save.close()

# Функция, открывающая запароленный файл
def open_passworded_file(path):
    f = open(path, 'r')
    encoded_data = f.read()
    f.close()

    json_text = base64.b64decode(encoded_data.encode()).decode()
    data = json.loads(json_text)
    password = sd.askstring(title="Ввод данных", prompt="Введите пароль")
    if password == data['password']:
        return data['text']
    else:
        mb.showerror('Ошибка','Неверный пароль')
```

Comment: Как можно закодировать?

Comment: @Ivan_Vinichuk, добавил

Comment: def open_passworded_file(path):
    global url
    url = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir= os.getcwd(), title ='Виберіть Файл',filetypes=(('Текстові файли','*.txt'),('Всі файли','*.*')))
    f = open(path, 'r')
    data = json.loads(f.read())
    f.close()
    password = sd.askstring(title="Ввод данных", prompt="Введите пароль")
    if password == data['password']:
        return data['text']
    else:
        mb.showerror('Ошибка','Неверный пароль')

Comment: У меня ошибки кидает

Comment: Ошибка missing reguired positional argument: 'path'

Comment: @Ivan_Vinichuk, Добавьте пример к вопросу, пожалуйста, а то тут не удобно читать

Comment: https://prnt.sc/s03a7c скриншот кода

Comment: Скриншот ошибки https://prnt.sc/s03am7

Comment: @Ivan_Vinichuk
Сейчас добавлю с вашим примером

Comment: @Ivan_Vinichuk в случае с сохранением у вас тоже полезут ошибки. Можете куда-нибудь мне скинуть полный код? почта - grigandal625@gmail.com

Comment: сейчас скину!!!

Comment: Скинул моя почта ivan.vinichuk@ukr.net

Answer (score 0):

Я использую модуль pickle.

```
import pickle
def write(text, password, way):
    data = {
        'password' : password,
        'text' : text
            }
    file = open(way, 'wb')
    pickle.dump(data, file)
    file.close()
def read(way, password):
    file = open(way, 'rb')
    data = pickle.load(file)
    file.close()
    if password == data['password']:
        return data['text']
    else:
        print('Error, wrong password')
```